# How to add bold text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add bold text to my website using javascript, but it literly shows the `"<b>"`. How do i fix this?

```
var TextBox = document.getElementById("TextBox");

TextData.textContent = "<b> hello </b>"
```

I tried using the `document.write("");` , but it changes the whole website. Any Suggestions?

Comment: You can use css and then add it to the element with jquery...

Comment: I need to add it with javascript.

Comment: Why can't you use CSS for this? Using `#TextBox::first-word {font-weight:bold}` would surely do it for you?

Comment: @jaunt Probably some generated CSS.

Answer (score 15):

You can add first the content to textbox like this:

```
TextBox.innerHTML = "Hello";
```

then add its style like this:

```
TextBox.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

Or you can do it setting the `innerHTML` property of the element, just like this:

```
 TextBox.innerHTML = "<b>Hello</b>";
```

I tend to set style separately. You should avoid adding style like this, better use css classes.

Answer (score 5):

```
TextBox.innerHTML = "<b> hello </b>"
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the tag's surrounding spaces did matter inside `innerHTML`'s string. Is it required by the standard, or could it be a browser-specific issue?

Answer (score 2):

Toggle/add a css class on the containing element (TextBox).

```js
document.getElementById('TextBox').className = 'bold';
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='TextBox'>
    My text.
</div>
```

Or something like that.