# How can i make a certain word bold in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have this array of question written in js. And i access to my html using this:

```
const questionIndex = availableQuestion[arrayReady[currentPage-1]];
currentQuestion = questionIndex;
questionText.innerHTML = currentQuestion.q;
```

how can i make a certain word like = "not","except" from currentQuestion.q bold?

Comment: wrap it in `<strong>` tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add bold text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531609/how-to-add-bold-text-using-javascript)

Comment: Can you show us an example of a `question` ? or the array of `questions` ?

Comment: @Bravo ah, big thanks. didnt know that you can still wrap a html tag in js

Answer (score 3):

You need a list of words to be bolded, iterate over them, find them in `currentQuestion.q`, and then bold them.

```js
const currentQuestion = {}
currentQuestion.q = "This is not a not really except good question."

console.log(currentQuestion.q)

const boldWords = ["not", "except"]

boldWords.forEach(word => {
  currentQuestion.q = currentQuestion.q.replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "g"), makeBold("$1"))
})

console.log(currentQuestion.q)

function makeBold(str) {
  // your bold implementation
  return str.bold()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I viewed all the answers, but I have developed a more browser compatible code compared to the already existing answers. Please have a look below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a string in bold.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const str = "Hello Javesh, How are you doing today?"; //your question
  const result = str.split(" ");
  const keywords = ["Hello", "How"]; // your keywords
  for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
     if(keywords.includes(result[i])){       
       document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML += "<b>"+result[i]+"</b>"+" ";
     }else{
       document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML +=result[i]+" ";
    }
  }  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `bold()` function is depreciated as its functionality can vary per browser.

Here's the MDN reference for the `bold()` function:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `bold()` function and combine it with a loop and conditions

Answer (score 0):

You could use bold() <- (that's a function) and use it with loops/conditions

Comment: Take a look again at [answer]. This isn't enough detail to be a good answer, but it's just copied from another answer that also needs more detail

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.